# Is it possible to animate a newly loaded image in a PFImageView? Relates to parse.com PFImageView

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, parse-platform

I'm creating a PFImageView with a default image. I'm then loading an image in the background and when the image is finished downloading from the server it is immediately shown and the placeholder/default image is replaced. The problem is that the transition from the default to the downloaded image isn't very pleasant. Is there a way to create a fade out of the default and fade in to the downloaded animation?

Here's my code.

```
// set the pfImageView into the webView
_pfImageView = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dpTall.jpg", [self.drink.glassId intValue]]]];
_pfImageView.frame = CGRectMake(244, 0, 76, 114);
[webView.scrollView addSubview:_pfImageView];

// create a query for finding images on Parse
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Images"];
[query whereKey:@"drinkId" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.drink.primaryKey]];

    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
        _pfImageView.file = imageFile;
        [_pfImageView loadInBackground];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"PFQuery Error:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of transition are you looking for?

Comment: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion I think it would be easier to drop the dependency on PFImageView and just use a normal UIImageView and set that with a place holder first, like you are currently doing.  Then in your getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock completion block starting at the IF statement do something like this....

```
if(!error)
{
    PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"image"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *data = [imageFile getData];

        if(data)
        {
            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

                [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 
                animations:^{ 
                    //imageView is your UIImageView you are trying to set/change
                    imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
                } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                    animations:^{ 
                        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        imageView.alpha = 1.0f;
                    } 
                    completion:^(BOOL finished)
                    {
                    }];  
                }];//outside block
            });
        }
        else
        {
           //no data error handling here
        }                

    });
else
{
    //error handling here
}
```

disclosure: I am not near a compiler so I did not run this code yet.

You also instead of doing the outside dispatch_async you could just do use the imageFile getdata method call with a completion block (its on parse.com website API) and then put everything from if(data) down in that block instead of the async block I made.  I'm just used to doing it this way.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I just suggested to Parse that they add in a new property for their PFImageView class that allows us to set a transition property. But until then your solution will work just fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a category on PFImageView to get a cross fade animation each time an image appears :

```
@implementation PFImageView (Utility)

// Add a fade animation to images
-(void) setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if ([self.layer animationForKey:KEY_FADE_ANIMATION] == nil) {
        CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
        crossFade.duration = 0.6;
        crossFade.fromValue  = (__bridge id)(self.image.CGImage);
        crossFade.toValue = (__bridge id)(image.CGImage);
        crossFade.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        [self.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:KEY_FADE_ANIMATION];
    }

    [super setImage:image];
}

@end
```

You just need a placeholder image so the animation can occur the first time.